# Use drop down list as query string

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, query-string

I have a drop-down list inside a form

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select>
        <option>ABC</option>
        <option>xyz</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

When an item is clicked, I want the user to be directed to a new page (i.e. 'newPage.aspx'), and this page will display the chosen option, e.g. inside a label (Label1)

I also have the 2 options stored in an array -> 
myArray = new Array("ABC", "xyz"), if that helps

Comment: why don't you put an anchor inside each option with an href directing to the page?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Are you having a problem doing so?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery it:

```
  $('select','#myForm').change(function() {
    document.location.href = "/newPage.aspx?value=" + $(this).val();
  });
```

Better solution (submitting the form, more friendly to search engines) would be:

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" method="get" action="newPage.aspx">
  <select name="mySelect">
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
  $('select','#myForm').change(function() {
     $('#myForm').submit();
  });
```

Comment: You need to give the `<select>` a `name`, and give the `<option>` a `value` for `.submit` to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your drop-down list an ASP.NET server control (since you're using aspx)
2. In your codebehind, get the selected value from the dropdown list
3. In your codebehind, Response.Redirect to the URL (newpage.aspx?value=ABC)

Answer (score 0):

Currently untested, but I think this should work:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('myForm').getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

sel.onchange() = function(){
    var val = this.getElementsByTagName('option')[this.selectedIndex],
        url = 'http://newPage.aspx?option=',
        queryUrl = url + encodeURIComponent(val);

    window.location = queryUrl;
});
```

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`element.getElmentsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`element.onchange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange).
- [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).
- [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).